# OpenCV Native Samples are not building

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I have spent a long while trying to get this thing to work, and I think my error is very trivial but I have been unable to fix it. Plus, I know there have been questions about this before but none have helped me solve my issue.

I am using the android-opencv library in eclipse juno

When I build the sample, I will use sample 4 as an example, I get this message in my console:

```
15:29:35 **** Build of configuration Default for project org.opencv.samples.tutorial4.Sample4Mixed ****
"C:\\dev\\android-ndk-re8b-windows\\ndk-build.cmd" 
Cannot run program "C:\dev\android-ndk-re8b-windows\ndk-build.cmd": Launching failed

Error: Program "C:\dev\android-ndk-re8b-windows\ndk-build.cmd" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2011a Student\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell]

15:29:35 Build Finished (took 54ms)
```

Where are the double \'s coming from?!

Also I did define my environmental variable NDKROOT to be the absolute path to my ndk. But to be even more safe, I defined it again in my properties->c/c++ build path.

HELP

Comment: May I know your ndk path in your system because ndk get problem with space in folder

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Head to the project's properties. If you're using Windows, the shortcut is `Alt + Enter`; or simply right-click the project name to find its properties.
2. Go to the `C/C++ Build` section; under `Builder Settings` tab in `Build command:` text box you're likely to find something similar to that below, if it's empty then type in the similar text - namely: `${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd` where `NDKROOT`, as its name implies, refers to the path where your NDK root folder exists. [image]
3. Now you must inform eclipse what `NDKROOT` equates to; as in, where is the NDK root path. You can do this by heading to (in your project's properties) `C/C++ Build` > `Environment` > press `Add…`
4. Now add your environment variable named NDKROOT (the `Name`) with the relevant path (`Value`). Note that you're to repeat this per NDK project. You would get a window similar to that below.
   [image]
5. Press `OK` to the *New variable* input window and then `OK` again to the properties window.

Comment: i have followed all your instruction but still showing error.

Answer (score 8):

If you use Windows 7, you can set it like this:

1. Right click on "**My Computer**"
2. Click on "**Properties**"
3. Click on "**Advanced System**"
4. Make a new variable `NDKROOT`
5. Change the value to your NDK path
6. Restart Eclipse
7. Click "**OK**"