# Unable to launch cygpath in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cygpath

When i am trying to import a project to my workspace it shows an error

> [2013-03-17 16:14:15 - Unable to launch cygpath. Is Cygwin on the
>   path?] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cygpath":
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

this project contains jni libraries,it is a ndk based project.why this error happen i cant import this project to my system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466074/opencv-native-samples-are-not-building  ,get some useful information from here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

go to your project right click there.then take properties and select the c/c++ build and there you can see the build settings .and in the build settings give the path of ndk in your system like:

```
D:\android\android-ndk-r8d\ndk-build.cmd NDK_DEBUG=1
```

Now clean your project and run. Thats it.

Comment: i have same problem but can't feagure out with your solution

Comment: in build settings, where to give path ndk?? I don't find any way to give path of NDK. Can you please reply?

Comment: @ShirishHerwade, you can find it under C/C++ Build -> Environment, then add an environment variable named NDKROOT with the ndk path as its value.

Answer (score 3):

With NDK r8d, you don't need cygwin. Maybe the project you import was tuned for an older version, and maybe it defined **ndk-build.sh** as the C++ build command. You should use **ndk-build.cmd** or simply **ndk-build** (utilizing Windows command line conventions)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable

```
NDK_HOME = [your path to ndk]
```