# Unable to launch cygpath

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, cygpath

I am new to openCV and I downloaded it to work with it in Eclipse Juno.

I have download version 2.4.6 and I have download NDK version R9 and I am working on windows platform and still can't run the tutorials of openCV because of the following errors. I followed the steps on [this documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_dev_intro.html#android-dev-intro) .

I tried to change the path on the build path part (`C:\android-ndk\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd NDK_DEBUG=1`)

```
[2013-10-29 18:06:56 - Unable to launch cygpath. Is Cygwin on the path?] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cygpath": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[2013-10-29 18:07:12 - ManagerActivity] Manifest attribute 'minSdkVersion' is set to '@ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL@'. Integer is expected.
[2013-10-29 18:07:13 - package] Manifest attribute 'minSdkVersion' is set to '@ANDROID_SDK_VERSION@'. Integer is expected.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to launch cygpath in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459934/unable-to-launch-cygpath-in-android)

Comment: Looks like he tried that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed the problem which was:
NDK version r9 .. has some issues so i have installed version r8b which solved the problem and worked fine .. :))

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need Cygwin when using NDK-R9. I think it was integrated in with R8 (or whatever they did to get around it). So you can ignore that error. I get that error as well, I'm looking how to get rid of it. But this error does not stop me from compiling. I've been ignoring it.

As far as the other two errors, they mention it needs an integer value. You need to put this element into your Manifest.xml file:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

... Or use the API level range you plan to comply with