# OpenCV Example of FaceDetection does not run

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, opencv

I'm using OpenCV for Android.
The default example mentioned on the OpenCV website does not run.
console says...
{
22:16:40 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project OpenCV Sample - face-detection ****
"\ndk-build.cmd" 
Cannot run program "\ndk-build.cmd" (in directory "C:\Users\Parth Sane\workspace\OpenCV Sample - face-detection"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Error: Program "\ndk-build.cmd" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\WinSCP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\FAHClient;C:\Users\Parth Sane\Desktop\eclipse;]

22:16:40 Build Finished (took 410ms)
}

The Mixed processing example gives similar a similar error...

Help!! Other samples run well...

Comment: Add `ndk-build.cmd` to your path.

Comment: can you pls specify exactly where? Thanks!

Comment: Somewhere in: `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\WinSCP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\FAHClient;C:\Users\Parth Sane\Desktop\eclipse;` (Have you read the error message?)

Comment: lol the path is right... I got it with other samples but no sucess with this one....

Comment: maybe the sample is broken then?

Comment: could be... anyone else ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466074/opencv-native-samples-are-not-building this solved it!! but sample shows runtime error... Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your OpenCV Sample face detection project in Eclipse, go to Project Properties, and then open "C/C++ Build" tab on the left-hand-side list. There you'll see a default builder configuration. It will be pointing to:

```
${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd
```

You have to either change this entry right there to point to where your ***ndk-build*** script is, or define NDKROOT environmental variable pointing to the root of your Android NDK install.

Comment: I did that but it some how doesnt even work... Like given up on it... But thanks anyways....