# OpenCV 3.0 Static Initialization initDebug() failed

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection

I need to detect face on android. I am using OpenCV 3.0 and sample face detection from OpenCV.

I've followed the instructions from [Android Development with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization). But it seems like the static lib won't load.

Please advise on what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using and the errors, if any, that you are receiving? It is very difficult for others to help with the issue you are facing without these details.

Comment: Ok, so I figured from this post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466074/opencv-native-samples-are-not-building

Comment: @JimmieR.Houts Thanks for your attention but apparently my question has been answered in another post. Again thanks :)