# How to setup Android NDK environment in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am using Eclipse Juno. I am trying to install Android NDK. I downloaded the NDK from the Android Developer site. I can not configure Eclipse.

I followed the Android Developer documentation. They said:

> Launch Eclipse, which is installed as part of the Android SDK.
>
> Open Window > Preferences.
>
> In the pane on the left side of the Preferences window, select Android. The Android section expands, revealing a number of subsections.
>
> Select NDK. In the pane on the right side of the Preferences window, browse to the directory that contains the NDK.
>
> Click OK to return to the Package Explorer display.

But I can not find the NDK directoy in my Eclipse preference menu.

[image: Screen]

Please Let me know how to configure NDK in Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to edit your operating system $PATH variable to include the `/path/to/NDK`. Than in the eclipse go to `Windows > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Environment`. There you can add path to NDK directory

Comment: Ya. I already tried that. But I am getting this error. `Description Resource Path Location Type
Program "make" not found in PATH android-ffmpeg-tutorial01    C/C++ Problem`

Comment: take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466074/opencv-native-samples-are-not-building it may help you. In the question itself says that you should create an environmental variable named NDKROOT with absolute path to ndk directory.